# Clickonce deployment with wpf

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I've created a wpf application and its installer with Clickonce. But running installer on another computer causes exe file creation in Start-Programs-Microsoft. What should I do to make installer create a folder in Program files?
By the way, I also want a program to create a desktop shortcut, I put make the "Make desktop shortcut" checkbox enabled when customizing publishing options, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clickonce doesn't allow to specify a folder in Program Files, the solution was to create a Setup Project within the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Publisher name settings under Publish Options -> Description of the project properties in Visual Studio determines the folder under Program Files.

Answer (score 0):

I usually follow below steps. Hope it may helps

Steps
1.  Right click on the client project -> properties -> Publish tab

2. Publish folder location, installation URL(eg: http://LocalHost/Application/client/)
3. Click updates give same installation URL
4. Click options > give name and description for the application
5. Click Publish
6. Copy the files from Publish folder location and paste it in corresponding installation URL
7. Browse the install.htm
8. Click install
9. Some times before publishing you may need to create a new certificate (project properties -> signing tab > create test certificate (password not mandatory))